# Symlink on /usr/local/bin/ not working

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, symbolic-link

Can someone explain why this is not working??? I don't get it.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

As you can see, I have `/usr/local/bin` in there.

Then the error:

```
$ cmake
-bash: cmake: command not found
```

But I do have a symlink:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 27 09:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Jan 23 23:23 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20 Mar 27 09:07 cmake -> /opt/cmake/bin/cmake
```

And in fact, running it from inside the directory it works:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
./cmake
```

Any ideas?

Of course, if I edit my `.bashrc` and I add a line like:

```
export PATH="/opt/cmake/bin:$PATH"
```

Then it works. But that's not what I want to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue.  My PATH starts `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`, and `readlink -f /usr/local/bin/openssl` outputs `/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl`.  However, when I enter `openssl`, what gets executed is `/usr/bin/openssl`.  Makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons, here what you can do to check them:

1. Check that the `symlink` target is executable with this command `ls -la /opt/cmake/bin/cmake` if not, give the proper rights sudo `chmod +x /opt/cmake/bin/cmake`.
2. there can be another executable named `cmake` in the directories listed in your `PATH` variable, to check do this `which -a cmake`.
3. Check that there is not a single errors `PATH` variables, things like extra spaces.
4. Verify the symlink pointing `readlink -f /opt/cmake/bin/cmake`
5. Check if /opt/cmake/bin is in your PATH variable
6. Check that /opt/cmake/bin is not corrupted
7. Check in a different shell

Comment: Hi @Saxtheowl. Thanks for all the ideas. I checked all of them and they all seem to be correct. That is, 1) already has x permission ; 2) there isn't another one on PATH (`which` answers nothing) ; 3) I double checked and I don't see anything...

Comment: I have added more tests to do, if this still dont work im kinda lost here

Comment: Hi @Saxtheowl. Regarding 5), it is not. However, if I add it, it obviously work. But that's not what I wanted to do and that's why I made the symlink to somewhere I already had in the PATH. Do you know why adding /opt/cmake/bin to PATH seems to be necessary?